# Java: How to parse the AVL data packets coming from the Device FM4100?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm currently working on the java assignment to communicate with the remote GPS device which is communicating with the server via AVL data protocol 4100.

I'm getting the packets from the device but i'm not getting how to parse/decode it to get the actual data out of it.

Can someone please guide me to get this done ?
Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is too late to answer :)

I am working on the same thing these days, and unfortunately I couldn't find a good reference for developer. I guess each manufacturer having his way/protocol to send data.

any way, I got some good documents on this matter:
http://www.scribd.com/search?query=fm4200

of you have a good links on that .. I would appreciate that.